# GIT: Modifying files and commit with same date/time

Tags: c#, git, libgit2sharp

It seems that it is not easy possible to commit a file which a different content but with the same date/time.

Thw following situation:

- Create a git repository
- Add a file "foo.bar" with a defined date/time fpr creating/lastwrite (e.g. 2015-01-01 00:00:00)
- Commit this file
- Modify the "foo.bar" content and set the date/time again to the same value
- call "git status" => nothing to commit, working directory clean
- call "git commit" => No changes; nothing to commit

How can I force the commit!?

Here is a repro code with libGit2Sharp:

```
using System.IO;
using LibGit2Sharp;
using System;
namespace GitWorkingUpdateProblem01
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      const string repoDir = @".\git-Test";
      Repository.Init(repoDir);
      using (var repo = new Repository(repoDir))
      {
        string fileName = Path.Combine(repo.Info.WorkingDirectory, "foo.bar");
        var dt = new DateTime(2015, 01, 01, 00, 00, 00);
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
        {
          sw.WriteLine("UNIQUE-TEXT-1234");
        }
        File.SetLastWriteTime(fileName, dt); File.SetCreationTime(fileName, dt);

        repo.Stage(fileName); repo.Commit("1");

        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName, false))
        {
          sw.WriteLine("UNIQUE-TEXT-4321");
        }
        File.SetLastWriteTime(fileName, dt); File.SetCreationTime(fileName, dt);

        repo.Stage(fileName); repo.Commit("2"); // ==> THROWS: No changes; nothing to commit.
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could reproduce it even without `libgit2sharp` (using TortoiseGit & msysgit).

It's a known issue:
https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/312
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/Uo9TDppHTSI

I was able to get it to detect changes by running:
`git read-tree HEAD` in the console. If your library allows you to run this (or arbitrary) commands - it may help out as well.

In any case, this is something that deliberately fights against git, so I would advise against manually changing the `ModifiedDate` if possible.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the links! My problem is, that we do a migration and somethimes it happens that the file gets the same date/time... so I will try to "force" the "read-tree HEAD"... thanks!

Comment: The problem might even get worse with the Windows 7 SMB2 file information cache... https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff686200 hopefully no one is using SMB2...